# Rottweiler vs Presa Canario vs Cane Corso vs Bull Mastiff: How to choose?

Tags: dogs, breeds

I am trying to figure out why a person would choose one of the breeds above over the others. Any way I look at it the Rottweiler looks like the better option for about any task I can think of - smarter and more energetic than the other breeds yet just as big and protective as any of them.

And still people choose the other breeds sometimes, they are nowhere near going extinct.

What am I missing here? What are the advantages of the other breeds?

Comment: The way the question is worded, it sounds like you're asking "why do other people have different tastes than me?" Suggest rewording it if the intent was to ask what type of person each dog is most suited to.

Comment: Done As requested :-)

Answer (score 2):

That's like saying "I don't like brunettes. Why aren't they extinct yet?"

- People have different tastes and prefer different looks in dogs.
- All these dogs originate from different regions and are traditionally used in those regions
- All of them declined in numbers quite drastically until they found a new field of application in wars or police service
- There are enthusiasts trying to maintain a healthy population
- The different temperaments of these dogs makes some more appropriate for certain tasks than others

[Rottweiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rottweiler):

- Originates from Germany
- Used for herding and driving cattle and as police dogs
- Some growers have found that Rottweilers are especially suited to move stubborn stock that simply ignore Border Collies, Kelpies, and others. Rottweilers use their bodies to physically force the stubborn animal to do its bidding if necessary.
- Good natured and placid temperament, very devoted, obedient and eager to work, but high need to control

[Presa Canario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perro_de_Presa_Canario):

- Originates from the Canary Islands
- Used as watch dog, for protecting the herds (as opposed to *herding*), dog fighting, hunting wild boars (catch dog) and even as war dogs
- More agile than the other dog breeds in this list
- Requires early socialization and obedience training and can be aggressive toward other dogs and strangers, although they tend to display their agressiveness rather that act on it and bite

[Cane Corso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cane_Corso)

- Originates from Italy and Sicily
- Used as guard dog for herds and families
- Very affectionate and protective towards owners, loving with children and family, and easily trained
- Extremely protective, which might manifest in agressiveness towards strangers

[Bull Mastiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullmastiff)

- Originates from England
- Used as guard dog for people (as opposed to homes and herds), hound and police dog
- Signales danger silently (frowning) and is therefore not suited to protect herds from wild animals or strangers
- Training and socialization is of high importance, as the breed can be independent
- Very calm and self-confident, even in hectic situations or when provoced

Comment: Unfortunately most of the info there does not answer my question :-(

Comment: Well, I cannot tell you why people choose one over another because I cannot read peoples minds. Questions like that are usually closed as "primarily opinion based". These breeds are similar in many aspects, but not in all, which is what I was trying to point out